# Cant get the value of an ajax call in an action in mobx, instead I get Proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I just learned Mobx,

I have this simple setup where I have my store with some things like:

`selectedFood: "pizza"`

and some functions that do something like changing that selected value:

`selectFood: (food) => store.selectedFood = food,`

This is my basic store:

```
const StoreProvider = ({children}) => {
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    selectedFood: "pizza",
    selectFood: food => store.selectedFood = food,
    restaurantResults: [],
    getRestaurnts: () => {
        fetchRestaurants('pizza')
            .then(res => store.restaurantResults.push(res))
    },
  }))
  return <StoreContext.Provider value={store} >{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
}
```

Then on my component when a user clicks on a button I do two things, change the selectedFood to whatever the user clicked on, and also make an ajax call to get some food from an api:

```
const RestaurantsChooser = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);

  function handleClick(food) {
    store.selectFood(food);
    store.getRestaurants(food);
  }

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="pa2">
      <p>{store.selectedFood}</p>
        <button onClick={e => handleClick(e.target.value)}  value="pizza" className="pa2 bn br2 mh1">Pizza</button>
        <button onClick={e => handleClick(e.target.value)} value="burger" className="pa2 bn br2 mh1">Burger</button>
        <button onClick={e => handleClick(e.target.value)} value="sushi" className="pa2 bn br2 mh1">Sushi</button>
      <div className="flex">

        {store.restaurantResults.map((rest, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="pa2">
              <img src={rest.image_url} alt="restuarant"/>
              <p>{rest.name}</p>
              <p>Reviews{rest.review_count}</p>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

But when I try to loop over the `store.restaurantResults` i get a Proxy instead of the results, but if on the `getRestaurnts` function in my store i console the response of `fetchRestaurants` the results are there, but somehow they do not get passed to my component.

I think i need to do something about the ajax call in the store as its async but all i can find in the documentation is this link: https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html, which talks about stuff with classes, which looks totallly different than my setup, any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if  `getRestaurants` is a `mobx action` because you are trying to modify an observable (`restaurantResults`) from code that runs asynchronously (outside of the initial `action`)
So after you get the results from the async call you need to run the modifications on the observable inside the mobx action. You can use the `runInAction` mobx utility function.

```js
    getRestaurnts: () => {
        fetchRestaurants('pizza')
            .then(res => 
               runInAction(()=>{
                 store.restaurantResults.push(res)
                })
               )
    },
```

You can read more how to work with asynchronous code and mobx in the [official documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html).